# css position different in firefox compared to safari, chrome and explorer

Tags: css, firefox, position

I have trouble  positioning my sag dots precisely in Firefox - it sort of jumps up 1 pixel. 
My testsite is [here](http://www.e-kl.dk/test2.asp)
All looks fine in safari, explorer and chrome, but not in Firefox where the dots are not centered vertical.

My code:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="p-5HHFVdWOPzeTWuQbtHAhTRSJIHllkHxDcd0wmzOO0" />
<title>TEST</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href=".\favicon.ico"><link href="_e-klstyle2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<style type="text/css">
<!--
#quotes {
    position:absolute; 
    text-align: right;
    bottom:19px; 
    right: 200px;
    z-index: 55;
}
#ovalbar {
    position:absolute; 
    text-align: left;
    bottom:14px; 
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 15;

}
#dots {
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:13px; 
    right: 22px;
    z-index:30;
    }
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="dots">
<% 
quotetext = "why is my dots placed diffenrtly in firefox?"
dotcount=1
do while dotcount =< 5 
'--------------------------active---------------
if dotcount=3 then
    fill = "black"
else
    fill = "none"
end if

%>
<a href="index.asp?f=<%=dotcount%>">
<svg height="18" width="18">
  <circle cx="9" cy="9" r="5" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.7" fill="<%= fill %>" />
</svg>
</a>
<% 
dotcount=dotcount+1
loop %>
</div>

<div class="txt_EKL_quotes" id="quotes">
<%= quotetext %>
</div>

<div id="ovalbar">
<svg height="24" width="600">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="24" rx ="12" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.5" />
</svg>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using latest version of Firefox (v35), it is centered like in Google.

Comment: strangely not in my Firefox v 35.0 on macbook pro (retina)